# react-admin edit component does not call update function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm working on a react-admin application and having an issue where the `update` function in my dataProvider is not called when the 'Save' button is clicked under the edit view.

My App.js looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { setGlobal, getGlobal } from 'reactn';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import PrivateRoute from './Auth/PrivateRoute';
import UserLayout from './components/user/layout/Layout';
import AuthLayout from './components/auth/Layout';
import defaultGlobalState from './defaultGlobalState';
import portalApiDataProvider from "./providers/portalApiDataProvider";
import {Admin, ListGuesser, EditGuesser, ShowGuesser, Resource, Layout} from "react-admin";
import { UserList, UserEdit, UserShow } from '../src/components/admin/users';
import { AccountList } from "./components/admin/serviceAccounts";
import authProvider from "./providers/authProvider";

ReactGA.initialize(process.env.REACT_APP_GA_KEY);

const jwt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'));

setGlobal({ ...defaultGlobalState, jwt });

const App = () => {
  const { userId } = getGlobal();

  let location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
  }, [location]);

  return (
      <Admin dataProvider={portalApiDataProvider} authProvider={authProvider}>
          <Resource name="users" options={{label: 'Customer Profiles'}} list={UserList} show={UserShow} edit={UserEdit}/>
          <Resource name="serviceAccounts" list={AccountList}/>
      </Admin>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My UserEdit is as follows:

```
<Edit title={<UserTitle/>} {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput source="first_name" />
        <TextInput source="last_name" />
        <TextInput source="email" />
        <TextInput source="phone" />
        <TextInput source="default_account_number" />
        <BooleanInput source="validated" format={v => v === 1 ? true : false}/>
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

I've seen this issue brought up a couple of times, but without any details on resolution.  This link mentions using a Notification component in the Layout (I'm pretty sure I'm using the default layout), or disabling undo (which does work but is not ideal): https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3049

This link also discusses a similar issue with reference to a demo project, but I'm not able to find the relevant code: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5082

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the `undoable` prop on Edit is causing problem. Set it to false and it will call the update properly. I don't know why, I am using this under a special endpoint as a "sub-app", so might be due to conflicting routers, too tired to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `mutationMode` of `Edit` into `"pessimistic"`
So your  will be

```js
 <Edit
      {...props}
      mutationMode="pessimistic"
>
```

Document here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#mutationmode

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

`mutationMode="undoable"` which is the default leads to a bug when you try to redirect within the `mutationOptions` props `onSuccess` function.

This is because the `onSuccess` function is fired and a redirect occurs before the underlying mutation actually completes i.e. the user is redirected away before any mutation is called.

**Work Around**

The workaround is therefore ensuring that the `onSuccess` function is called only **after** the mutation completes. This can be done by `mutationMode="pessimistic"` since it will wait for the mutation to **actually** complete.

This behaviour is not well documented in the react admin docs - at least I was not able to find anything - the docs in fact specifically show an [example](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Edit.html#mutationoptions) of a redirect in the `onSuccess` function with no mention of this behaviour.

The [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Edit.html#redirect) specifically mention: "Note that the redirect prop is ignored if you set the mutationOptions prop. See that prop for how to set a different redirection path in that case."

**Solution**

My suggestion is - that if you require to redirect on a successful edit or creation of a record, simply use the [`redirect` prop](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Edit.html#redirect).